# XTZ price history API

Tags: api, indexer, oracle

I need a simple API that provides historical XTZ price against fiat currencies like USD and EUR, or other cryptocurrencies like BTC.

Ideally I just need to compose an HTTP `GET` request with a date/time and the pair (i.e. XTZ/EUR) and get back the price at that moment in time.

The source of the data should be from a well established exchange (Binance, Coinbase, etc) or an oracle like Chainlink or Harbinger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [coingecko api](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api), docs found [here](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation)

Some sample GET requests:

- Get all supported exchange rates (supports fiat and some crypto):

  https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchange_rates
- Get the current XTZ price in a supplied currency:

  https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=tezos&vs_currencies= `currency-code`
- Get the past 365 days of price at a given currency:

  https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/tezos/market_chart?days=365&interval=daily&vs_currency= `currency-code`

Answer (score 2):

You may check the [Kline/Candlestick data API](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data) from Binance.

So, for example to get the prices since last 24 hours, it will look like:
`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=XTZUSDT&interval=1d&limit=1000`